# css checkbox scale does not scale well on os x

Tags: html, css, macos

I want to create a visually bigger checkboxes.
I've read here that the only way to that is using the CSS transform scale:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

The problem is that on windows, browsers IE, FF and Chrome it looks perfect but on OS X Yosemite it looks 3 or even 4 times bigger than the original size (checked Chrome and Safari).

anyone knows how to solve this?

full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dulmanr/g3h3z1pf/1/

Comment: the un-prefixed transform should be placed at the end (but not sure if this will solve your issue) [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to alter native form elements is always a bit risky. Very often it causes strange behavior in the form elements, in this case it's OSX doing strange stuff.

When ever I need to make checkboxes and radiobuttons look different from the native elements I replace them altogether. Check http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ for more info on how to do this. Saved me in a couple of occasions. Browser support is decent too. IE9 and upwards supported.

Comment: This is a nice workaround but it will cost too much for me to apply this on all checkboxes on my application. Secondly, i could not succeeded in enlarging the checkboxes as well (because it is a css customized checkbox, but still a checkbox).

Comment: You can always make a custom image sprite with a normal and a selected state and show these accordingly through css. This too requires extra work, but sadly that's the cost of trying to alter native form elements. This is, however, the least time consuming way that I can come up with.